# Not able to alter field value/s using hook_views_pre_render or views api hook functions

Tags: 7, views, search

I have a search result page created using search api and views. My search result page is based on  [this](https://www.reinisfischer.com/custom-drupal-search-built-search-api-database-search-views) tutorial and it seems to work properly,however I need to tweak some field's output value and I used  `hook_views_pre_render` to try to alter the field values however I cant see my fields that I added from the views UI interface on the `$view->result` array  but  they are rendered on the page. All I see when I `krumo($view->result)` is (see attached image)[image].

I seem to only get  entity and entity_properties array but not the fields in the array. I need to access the field to make the necessary tweaks like we have in the normal `$view->result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific answer for your situation but I would like to advise you a better way of managing it.

Instead of rendering the views using `Fields` you can render each row by rendering as `Content` where you can choose a dedicated `View mode` which can be easily overridden using the standard `template_preprocess_node`.

This will bring a lot more flexibility in your Web application.

Comment: Thanks a million. This was something I was looking for a long time, although I did implement some other way, This will definitely be of use soon. Just FYI i didn't have the rendering option `Content` but I did have the `Rendered entity` which could be hooked by `preprocess_node` for my search api output.